# Creating string with varaibles using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc and maybe to some of my question will seem naive.

I have this code in view Index.chtml page:

[image]

I need to create in src attribute of the frame element string that has two varaibles session and weblayout but, it seems I am doing it's wrong.

And value of the session and weblayout will not generated and will be like this:

```
/mapserver201x/mapviewernet/ajaxviewer.aspx?SESSION= + session + &weblayout= + weblayout
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
if value of session is:654276345234GSAKJD333,   
and value of weblayout is: Library://Exercise/WebCast/Hello.weblayout
```

the result should be:

```
    /mapserver201x/mapviewernet/ajaxviewer.aspx?SESSION=654276345234GSAKJD333 
&weblayout=Library://Exercise/WebCast/Hello.weblayout
```

Any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<frame src="/mapserver201x/mapviewernew/ajaxviewer.aspx?session=@ViewData["sessionId"]&weblayout=@ViewData["webLayout"]" />
```

All you've done in your example is assigned the value of those `ViewData` keys to JavaScript variables which won't work as you have expected.

You would definitely benefit from an [introduction to MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) to get the basics.

Also, trying typing your code into your question instead of using an image, it makes it easier to apply an answer using your original code.